# For MLE, why does the information inequality imply identifiability

Tags: maximum-likelihood, identifiability

Let $X = \langle X_1, \dots, X_n \rangle^{\top}$ be a finite sample of observation $X$ where $X \sim \mathbb{P}_{\theta_0}$ with $\theta_0 \in \Theta$ and density $f_X(x; \theta_0)$. The true parameter $\theta_0$ is globally identifiable if

$$
\forall \theta \neq \theta_0 \implies 
\mathbb{P}[f_X(x; \theta) \neq f_X(x; \theta_0)]
> 0$$

My lecture notes then say that because of the information inequality for the log likelihood,

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0} [\ell_n(\theta)]
\leq
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[\ell_{n}(\theta_0)], \qquad \forall \theta \in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d.
$$

this implies global identification, i.e.

$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0} [\ell_n(\theta)]
<
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[\ell_{n}(\theta_0)], \qquad \forall \theta \neq \theta_0.
$$

I don't follow this last step. Why does the inequality become strict? How is this last inequality related to the definition of global identification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W$ and $U$ denote two continuous (for simplicity) r.v.s with densities $f_W(w)$ and $f_U(u)$. The expected value of the r.v. $Z:=f_W(U)/f_U(U)$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(Z)&=&\int_{S_U}\frac{f_W(u)}{f_U(u)}rd F_U(u)\\
&=&\int_{S_U}f_W(u)d u\\
&\leqslant&1, 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $S_U$ is the support of $f_U(u)$. Then, we use Jensen's inequality to get
$$E[\log(f_W(U)/f_U(U))]\leqslant\log(E[f_W(U)/f_U(U)])\leqslant\log(1)=0$$
Now, take $\log f_W(U)=L(\theta;U)$ and $\log f_U(U)=L(\theta_0;U)$, so that
$$
E[L(\theta;U)]-E[L(\theta_0;U)]=E[\log(f_W(U)/f_U(U))]\leqslant 0,
$$
which establishes the weak inequality.

Now, under global identification, $Z$ is a nondegenerate r.v., so that the inequality is strict.